# Cannot figure out lifetimes for processing reference after locally storing object

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to build something like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ab216c351ce91c5ff06a75ddb069339a&version=stable)):

```
struct X<'a> {
    s: &'a str,
}

struct Y<'a> {
    list: Vec<X<'a>>,
}

impl<'r> Y<'r> {
    fn process(&mut self, e: &'r X) {
        // do stuff
    }
    fn add(&mut self, e: X<'r>) {
        self.list.push(e);
        let new = self.list.last().unwrap();
        self.process(new)
    }
}
```

Conceptually this seems okay: `self` has a list which gets one thing added to it, then I can do some further processing on that thing, in the knowledge that the thing should live as long as `self`. However, the compiler doesn't agree:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:15:29
   |
15 |         let new = self.list.last().unwrap();
   |                             ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 13:5...
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 | /     fn add(&mut self, e: X<'r>) {
14 | |         self.list.push(e);
15 | |         let new = self.list.last().unwrap();
16 | |         self.process(new)
17 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:15:19
   |
15 |         let new = self.list.last().unwrap();
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'r as defined on the impl at 9:1...
  --> src/main.rs:9:1
   |
9  | impl<'r> Y<'r> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected &mut Y<'_>
              found &mut Y<'r>
```

It seems to me that `new` should clearly live as long as `self` (though maybe not as long as the mutable reference `&mut self`?), so I don't understand the problem here.

Comment: Does `X` derive `Copy`? Also, keep in mind that `Vec::last()` returns a reference to the element.

Comment: No, `X` does not derive `Copy`. Yes, I'm using `Vec::last()` here because I want a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I didn't understand how lifetimes for references into `Vec` storage are supposed to work. I was incrementally trying to store stuff (instances of `X`) into `self` through a mutable reference and, at the same time, use references to those instances to store them in `self` as well. However, references into a `Vec` are only stable while the `Vec` itself is immutable.

The solution, therefore, was to extract the `Vec` (`list`) from `Y`, initialize it fully before initializing my `Y` object, so that it is immutable throughout the lifetime of the `Y` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
fn process(&mut self, e: &'r X) {
```

This signature looks very suspicious and is probably wrong. Note that you're not specifying a lifetime for `X` here, but for the reference to it. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: I have references of type `X` (that outlive my instances of type `Y`), but I also have things that can be transformed into `X`es. For the latter, I need some stable storage that is guaranteed to live as long as `Y` so that I can pass references to the to-be-`X`es and store their contents into `Y`. Trying to fiddle with the lifetime of `e` in the signature for `process()` so far seems to only make the situation worse.

Comment: @djc why not just change it to `fn process(&mut self, e: &X)` or `e: &X<'r>`; why specify the lifetime of the reference at all?